# Converting the data to numeric from the pulled data from a website's table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My friends,

I'm working on the pulling dataset from a website with BeautifulSoup in python. I guess that the some of html codes in website have been written wrong. Although I can pull the data, I can't see some of them due to they are coded differently.. I tried to convert it but I couldn't handle. The problem is;

You can check the html codes preesing F12 and go to find 4,5,6 - 10,11,12 etc. (every 3 rows) =>  [the website link](https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/08-2020/ws-170600.html)

The codes I've wrotten the codes which pull the data from website's table;

```
    # Pulling and creating rows of the table
    rows = [row.text for row in table.tr]

    texts = []
    for table in soup.find_all("table", {"class": "medias mensuales numspan"}):
        for tbody in table:
            for tr in tbody:
                te = tr.get_text()
                texts.append(te)
```

You can observe that, it can successfully pull the data but every 3 rows were missed. (I guess it is because of website's design) Some of the rows are coded like;

```
<span class="nthj"></span>
<span class="nttu"></span>
<span class="ntzb"></span>
<span class="ntyc"></span>
<span class="nttn"></span>
<span class="ntbb"></span>
<span class="ntde"></span>
<span class="ntyc"></span>
<span class="ntfs"></span>
```

I observed that every class corresponds a number. I don't know which language it is. If you know please let me know. I can code them.

**My question:** I have to convert these datas to numeric to avoid the missed data. Is there any way to fix/convert/pull via class name/ it?

If you need any details, feel free to contact me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the page is using CSS style to inject numbers to table. You can use this script to reinject the numbers back using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/08-2020/ws-170600.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# replace all <span class="..."> with their number form:
style = soup.select_one('.medias').find_previous('style').string
mapper = dict(re.findall(r'([^.]+?)::after{content:"(.*?)"', style))
for span in soup.find_all('span', class_=lambda cl: cl in mapper):
    span.replace_with(mapper[span['class'][0]])

# print table to screen:
for row in soup.select('.medias tr'):
    tds = [td.text for td in row.select('td') if td.text.strip()]
    print(tds)
```

Prints:

```
['1', '26.5', '32', '21.8', '-', '70', '0', '10', '15.2', '29.4', '46.5']
['2', '26.2', '31', '22.8', '-', '56', '0', '10', '21.7', '31.7', '44.3']
['3', '25.4', '29', '22.4', '-', '57', '0', '10.5', '20.7', '33.5', '48.2']
['4', '25.4', '29', '22.7', '-', '64', '0', '10', '19.6', '31.7', '48.2']
['5', '25.8', '30', '22.7', '-', '58', '0', '10', '19.8', '33.5', '46.5']
['6', '26.2', '30', '23', '-', '68', '0', '10', '19.8', '33.5', '44.3']
['7', '27', '32', '23.9', '-', '68', '0', '10', '19.6', '33.5', '42.4']
['8', '27.2', '30', '24.6', '-', '70', '0', '10', '20.7', '35.2', '51.9']
['9', '26.8', '30.1', '25', '-', '71', '0', '10.5', '27.4', '44.6', '59.4']
['10', '26.9', '31', '23.9', '-', '59', '0', '10', '20.9', '33.5', '48.2']
['11', '26.9', '31', '21.3', '-', '57', '0', '10', '16.5', '27.8', '42.4']
['12', '27.9', '32', '23.3', '-', '48', '0', '10.3', '17.8', '27.8', '40.7']
['13', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
['14', '25.5', '29', '22.9', '-', '53', '0', '10', '19.4', '29.4', '42.4']
['15', '25.4', '30', '22', '-', '54', '0', '10', '19.8', '31.7', '44.3']
['16', '24.8', '28', '22.5', '-', '55', '0', '10', '22.6', '33.5', '50']
['17', '24.8', '28', '22', '-', '50', '0', '10', '22', '31.7', '51.9']
['18', '24.5', '28', '21.2', '-', '62', '0', '10', '17.2', '25.9', '38.9']
['19', '25', '30', '19.7', '-', '62', '0', '10', '13.1', '22.2', '31.3']
['20', '22.7', '25.2', '19', '-', '74', '2.03', '10', '10.9', '29.4', '40.7', 'o']
['21', '24.7', '29', '20', '-', '72', '-', '10', '16.1', '27.8', '38.9', 'o']
['22', '25.2', '32', '19.3', '-', '70', '0', '10.1', '11.7', '24.1', '33.5']
['23', '25.7', '30', '21.3', '-', '64', '0', '10', '18', '31.7', '46.5']
['24', '25.8', '30', '22.8', '-', '67', '0', '10', '19.1', '31.7', '46.5']
['25', '25.7', '30.4', '22', '-', '61', '0', '10', '15.2', '25.9', '37']
['26', '24.7', '28', '20.8', '-', '71', '0', '10', '14.6', '29.4', '42.4']
['27', '24.5', '29', '19', '-', '68', '0', '10', '10.6', '20.6', '25.9']
['28', '26', '33', '18', '-', '50', '0', '10', '14.3', '25.9', '42.4']
['29', '27', '32', '22.8', '-', '55', '0', '10', '21.1', '31.7', '44.3']
['30', '26.4', '31', '23', '-', '68', '0', '10', '17', '29.4', '40.7']
['31', '25.3', '29', '22.6', '-', '69', '0', '10', '14.6', '25.9', '40.7']
[]
['25.7', '30', '21.9', '-', '62.4', '2.03', '10', '17.9', '30.1', '2', '0', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way to undo the double coding of the values in some (but not all) the rows in the table. This uses css selectors, pandas and string manipulation, but not regex:

```
import pandas as pd
#first, explicity undo the encoding:

    styles= soup.select_one('h3 + style')
    code_dict = {}        
    for s in styles:
        for i in s.split('.numspan')[1:]:
            code = i.split('span.')[1].split('::')
            code_val = code[1].split(':"')[1].split('"')[0]
            code_dict[code[0]] = code_val
```

Now that we have a dictionary of codes and code values, we can use that for the coded rows, or use the plain text for the uncoded ones:

```
rows = []
columns = []
for tr in table:
    for t in tr.select('th'):
        columns.append(t.text)
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "medias mensuales numspan"})
for tr in table:
        row = []
        for t in tr.select('td'):
            if len(t.select('span'))>1: #these are the coded rows
                hidden = [] #create a list to house the encrypted codes
                for s in t.select('span'):
                    hidden.append(s['class'][0])
                item = '' #now use the dictionary to convert them and create the actual value
                for h in hidden:                    
                    item +=(code_dict[h])
                row.append(item)                
            else:
                row.append(t.text)            
        rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows[1:-2],columns=columns[:-1])
```

Output (pardon the formatting):

```
    Day     T   TM  Tm  SLP     H   PP  VV  V   VM  VG  RA  SN  TS  FG
0   1   26.5    32  21.8    -   70  0   10  15.2    29.4    46.5                
1   2   26.2    31  22.8    -   56  0   10  21.7    31.7    44.3                
2   3   25.4    29  22.4    -   57  0   10.5    20.7    33.5    48.2                
3   4   25.4    29  22.7        64      10  19.6    31.7    48.2                
4   5   25.8    30  22.7        58      10  19.8    33.5    46.5                
5   6   26.2    30  23      68      10  19.8    33.5    44.3                
6   7   27  32  23.9    -   68  0   10  19.6    33.5    42.4
```

etc.

Comment: This also worked.! You're great, too. Thanks a lot.